# Optimize a file writing operation in OCaml?

Tags: file, optimization, ocaml, ml

basically in my project, I am trying to write a list of strings into file like this:

```
val mutable rodata_list : (string*string) list = []
.....
let zip1 ll =
   List.map (fun (h,e) -> h^e) ll in
let oc = open_out_gen [Open_append; Open_creat] 0o666 "final_data.s" in
  List.iter (fun l -> Printf.fprintf oc "%s\n" l) (zip1 rodata_list);
```

Here is my problem, usually the `rodata_list` can reach as long as 800,000 size, and the above code on our server (`64-bit, 32 core Intel(R) Xeon(R) CPU E5-2690 0 @ 2.90GHz`)  takes about 3.5 seconds..   The `OCaml` version I use is `4.01.0`.

This is not acceptable, especially as I have 4 piece of code like this to write into a file. Totally they could take me over 15 seconds..

I tried this:

```
Printf.fprintf oc "%s\n" (String.concat "\n" (zip1 rodata_list));
```

But no obvious improvement..

So I am wondering that, how to optimize this part? I appreciate any solutions. Thank you!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

1. Don't use `^` to concatenate a bunch of strings in performance critical code, as it will lead to quadratic complexity;
2. Try not to rely on `*printf` functions, when performance matters (although in OCaml 4.02 it is pretty fast);
3. Don't apply several iterations on a list in a row, since OCaml doesn't have a deforesting. Try to do as much operations in an iteration as possible;
4. If you're using lists of 1 million elements, then you're actually doing something wrong. Try to use different data structure;

So, given the advices above we have the following:

```
List.iter (fun (x,y) -> 
  output_string oc x;
  output_string oc y;
  output_char oc '\n') rodata_list
```

Also, any optimizations should start from profiling, to get the profile you need to compile it with profiling info, for example like this:

```
 ocamlbuild myprogram.p.native
```

Then you can run program to collect the profile, that can be read with `gprof`. My guess, that you will spend all the time not in the actual IO, or even concatenation, but in garbage collection, since your zip, will create millions of string.

### How fast it should be

So to proof, that you're actually trying to optimize wrong part of your code, I've wrote this small program:

```
let rec init_rev acc = function
  | 0 -> acc
  | n -> init_rev (("hello", "world") :: acc) (n-1)

let () = List.iter (fun (x,y) -> 
  print_string x;
  print_endline y) (init_rev [] 1000_000)
```

It creates a list of one million elements and outputs it:

```
$ ocamlbuild main.native 
$ time ./main.native > data.txt

real    0m0.998s
user    0m0.211s
sys     0m0.783s
```

This is on macbook laptop. Moreover we spend most of the time in the system, with only 200ms in OCaml. And a simple loop for 1000_000 iterations without creating a list, takes only 11ms.

So, profile.

Comment: Hello ivg, I tried your advice, and total time of three file writing snippets in my code reduced from around 8.5 seconds to 6 seconds. Is there anything else I can do?

Comment: BTW: If it is not `list`, then what is the proper data structure for around 1 million elements?

Comment: that's because you're trying optimize something, that you think is slow, but actually the bottleneck is somewhere else. You need to profile your code. I'll update my post with proof.

Comment: what concerning a proper data structure, it is hard to give a good answer, without knowing the details. Maybe you even do not need to store data at all, and work incrementally. Otherwise, using arrays or strings can give a good performance.

Comment: @computereasy: I think what ivg is trying to tell you is "how do you create your `rodata_list`?" Maybe you can directly print your elements instead of putting them in a list before printing.

Comment: Can you give a citation for `^` having quadratic complexity? I can't imagine that that could possibly be true. Or did you mean that using it to concatenate a list of strings into a single string would lead to quadratic complexity. Because that's not what's happening in the OP's code. That is, unless there's something fundamentally weird about `^`, the OP's `zip1` should be linear in the number of characters in `ll`.

Comment: I meant not that '^' by itself is quadratic, but that reducing a list to a string using this operator will be quadratic, see [documentation](http://caml.inria.fr/pub/docs/manual-ocaml/libref/Buffer.html) for a `Buffer` module, for example. I will update the post to make it more explicit about this.

Comment: @ivg Yes, but again that's not what `zip1` is doing. `zip1` is linear in the number of characters in `ll` regardless of whether you're using `^` or a mutable buffer (or rather `List.length ll` mutable buffers).

Comment: totally agree, in the OPs example there is now quadratic performance incurred by the "drastic" `^` operator.